# unable to route to action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

In my view i have a  tag like the following

```
<a href="@Url.Action("LaunchApp", "ClinicalDocument")" class="btn btn-dark inline" title="Request CCDA">CCDA</a>
```

when i click the the link, i get the 404 error.  This action is in a new controller i added to project.

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /ClinicalDocument/LaunchApp

Here is my controller code

```
namespace PatientPortal.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize]
    //[InitializeSimpleMembership]
    //[SessionTimeoutFilter]
    public class ClinicalDocumentController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ClinicalDocument/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LaunchApp()
        {
            QuickLaunch model = new QuickLaunch();

            return Redirect(model.Url);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Route.config

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //defaults: new {  controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
}
```

I am not sure why its throwing 404 error.  Everything seems to look ok.  Please help.

Update:

I see the following in debug output in visual studio

> Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.Mvc.dll Exception thrown: 'System.Web.HttpException' in System.Web.dll

after i click on the link

Comment: Show how you construct the routes in startup, and your controller dependencies please.

Comment: Also, please confirm that LaunchApp is in ClinicalDocumentController, and that you have a LaunchApp view.

Comment: i dont have LaunchApp view.  Actually what i want to do is "return Redirect(model.Url)".  i will update code.

Comment: What is `model.Url`, and what is the actual url shown in the error message that your attempting to redirect to

Comment: @Stephen Muecke - I put a breaking point right after the open brace in LaunchApp, it doesn't even hit the breakpoint.

Comment: The code you have shown will redirect to the `LaunchApp()` method. What are the details of the error message - it will tell you the url that you trying to redirect to.

Comment: its throwing error before even going to Redirect

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /ClinicalDocument/LaunchApp

Comment: You will not get that error based on the code you have shown. Its something you have not shown causing the issue.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Is your ClinicalDocument controller inside an area ?

Comment: @Shyju - No I am not using Areas.

Comment: So when you access `yourSite/ClinicalDocument/LaunchApp`, It is giving you the 404 for that endpoint ? ( comment out the Redirect code for now and do a `return Content("works");`)

Comment: @Shyju - Same error

Answer (score 0):

So problem was the build path.  It was set to a virtual directory S:/.  After I added new controller, I changed the build path to bin/.  That fixed the issue.